# Proper way to error handle

Tags: php

This is more of a architectural question. I like to know what people's opinion on how to properly handle errors in a fully Object Oriented PHP environment.

For example I have a class that retrieves all user data from the database. So I would use it in this way:

```
$userData = new UserDataConnection();
$userData->openDatabase();
$userData->retrieveData();
$userData->showData();
$userData->closeDatabase();
```

At each of these steps, an error could have potentially occurred. So would I return a boolean from each step stating whether the function has successfully executed (hence the error checking is within each function), or do I do a try-catch exception handling around the whole thing? or is there a better way?

Is it also better to always go to some kind of error page when some kind of error occur?

Comment: Exceptions are good , Since you can even catch unmatched exceptions. But error handling mostly depends upon programmer and their style, not some preset standards there to follow.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best way to handle errors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4227749/best-way-to-handle-errors)

Comment: It's true that people have preferences and style, but I'm just looking for advise as I'm not originally a PHP programmer. Most of the example out there are based on a non-object oriented approach using or die() to stop a script prematurely which seems very un-OO and messy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php

$ERROR = false;
try {

    $userData = new UserDataConnection();
    $userData->openDatabase();
    $userData->retrieveData();
    $DETAILS = $userData->showData();
    $userData->closeDatabase();

} catch( Exception $e ) {

    $ERROR = $e->getMessage(); // exit;

}

if( $ERROR ) {
    $DETAILS = array();
}

?>
```

If you are using PDO you can throw a PDOException.

Comment: Does $e->getMessage() automatically retrieve the error message from a mySQLi database object? Or will I need to throw it within the function call?

Comment: You will have to throw it or use PDO and capture PDOException.

Answer (score 1):

It typically boils down to a simple question:

*May this function "legitimately" fail or is any failure a sign of something being really wrong?*

If a function expects a certain kind of input and should never ever be called with a different kind of input, any failure to supply the correct input is an `InvalidArgumentException`. This is especially true for functions which do not directly handle user input. This works even better with type hinting.

If a function should always produce a certain result given the correct input, any failure of the function to produce that result is a `RuntimeException` or `LogicException` or some other kind of exception.

If a function may or may not produce some kind of result, `false` is a legitimate return value. Functions which deal with user input and therefore get very arbitrary input values are often fine with returning `false`.

Some examples:

- `getDatabaseConnection()` is perfectly correct in throwing a `RuntimeException` or similar if it cannot establish a connection to the database. This is an *exceptional circumstance* in which case no work can continue.
- `transformFooIntoBar(Foo $foo)` is correct in throwing some form of exception if it cannot return a `Bar` instance, for whatever reason that may be. The function has a clear purpose and a type checked input value. If it cannot do its job under such clear conditions, something is clearly wrong and must be fixed. Ergo, an exception.
- `checkIfUserExists($id)` may well return `false`, because its job is to return a thumbs up or thumbs down. A user not existing is not an *exceptional circumstance* given this job description.

Where to catch a thrown exception depends on where you want to deal with it. Database connection errors should probably be caught at the very top of the call stack, since you probably cannot do anything if the database is down.
On the other hand, if some module is calling some submodule and half expects that submodule to fail and/or has a contingency plan in case it does fail, the module may catch the exception of the submodule and continue on doing its job. For instance `getRSSUpdates()` makes a call to a `HTTP::fetchContents($url)`. If the URL returns a 404, the `HTTP` module may throw an exception, since it cannot return contents under these circumstances. The `getRSSUpdates()` function is prepared for this though and handles this case as "no updates at this time".